# Ubuntu 22.04.2 UEFI Boot causes black screen?

Tags: boot, uefi, amd-graphics, gigabyte

This is a new pc build with a gigabythe B550M DS3H AC mb, ryzen 5 5500 cpu, 32gb corsair ram, WD2TB M2 drive and a 500W power supply. Initially I put it together with my 10 yr old PNY GeForce GT 610 gpu. Installed Lubuntu 22.04. Everything worked fine. Bought a new Radeon RX580 8GB card and put that in. It also worked fine for about a month. Then a week or so ago after some updates said reboot required it booted up to a black screen. After a couple days of searching this problem and trying various fixes still nothing. I think it may be a UEFI problem. If I boot from the grub menu into recovery mode I do get a gui but monitor only gets 1024x768 . If I boot from a usb in bios mode and into safe graphics mode I get my normal resolution. So it seems like the gpu is ok but how do I boot a bios mode into this safe graphics mode or make these settings permanent? I have tried setting nomodeset in grub but all that did was allow me to log in to a tty terminal. Other graphics are still not there. Any help is appreciated!

Update: So seems like it was the gpu. I went back to the seller on Amazon and they sent me a new one that works just fine.

Comment: As usual with old devices: Check the bios battery!

Comment: This is a brand new motherboard.